# Why can toluene be chlorinated at either the benzylic position or the ring depending on the conditions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, radicals, regioselectivity

My book mentions a reaction for the preparation of benzaldehyde with toluene in which side chain chlorination of toluene gives (dichloromethyl)benzene, which upon hydrolysis gives benzaldehyde:

[image: Synthesis of benzaldehyde from toluene]

Why does the chlorination occur at the methyl group and not the aromatic ring in this case? Also, why chlorination with $\ce{FeCl3/Cl2}$ lead to 2-chlorotoluene (and 4-chlorotoluene), without any chlorination of the methyl substituent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The halogenation of toluene is possible by two mechanisms. In German, they are referred to by the shorthands *KKK* and *SSS*, where *KKK* stands for ***K***atalysator, **K**älte, **K**ern (**c**atalyst, **c**old and **c**ore) while *SSS* is ***S***onne, **S**iedehitze, **S**eitenkette (**s**un, **s**izzling heat and **s**ide chain).

At low temperatures and in the presence of an activating catalyst such as $\ce{FeCl3}$, halogenation of toluene will typically occur as phenyl ring halogenation following the electrophilic aromatic substitution mechanism.

[image: Mechanism of *KKK*]
**Scheme 1:** Catalytic chlorination of toluene with $\ce{Fe^3+}$ as a catalyst. *ortho*- and *para*-products expected; (*para* not shown) mesomeric structures of the intermediate not shown.

Und higher temperatures and irradiation, halogenation takes place according to a radical chain mechanism.

[image: Mechanism of *SSS*]
**Scheme 2:** Radical chlorination of toluene under irradiation. Multiple chlorination possible. Mesomeric structures of the benzyl radical not shown.

---

The electrophilic aromatic substitution is, of course, not as easily possible on the benzylic carbon; we would somehow need a free electron pair to appear there — not likely.

On the other hand, if a chlorine radical attempted to remove a hydrogen of the phenyl ring, that would result in a radical that cannot be delocalised (the $\ce{C-H}$ bond is orthogonal to the π-system) which is therefore very unstable. Another way of looking at it is to consider the $\ce{C–H}$ bond strengths: weaker bonds are more easily cleaved homolytically, as is the case in free-radical halogenation. Aryl $\ce{C–H}$ bonds are roughly $\pu{100 kJ/mol}$ stronger than benzylic $\ce{C–H}$ bonds ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon%E2%80%93hydrogen_bond)), so radical abstraction preferentially occurs at the benzylic position.

Answer (score 5):

1. Upon excitation, homolytic cleavage of the $\ce{Cl-Cl}$ bond occurs:
   $$\ce{Cl2 ->[$h\nu$] 2Cl*}$$
2. The resulting chlorine radical abstract a hydrogen atom (**not a proton!**) from the methyl group of toluene, yielding a benzyl radical.

$$\ce{Ph-CH3 + Cl* -> Ph-CH2* + HCl}$$
The benzyl radical may either

3. react with $\ce{Cl2}$:

$$\ce{Ph-CH2* + Cl2 -> Ph-CH2Cl + Cl*}$$

or undergo radical recombinations, such as 
$$\ce{2 Ph-CH2* -> Ph-CH2-CH2-Ph}$$ or
$$\ce{Ph-CH2* + Cl* -> Ph-CH2Cl}$$

Taking into consideration that the radical concentrations are typically much lower than that of $\ce{Cl2}$, these recombination steps are much less likely than the reaction of the benzyl radical with a chlorine molecule.

Benzyl chloride, the primary reaction product of the photochlorination may again serve as a hydrogen atom donor in a further reaction with chlorine radicals:

4. $$\ce{Ph-CH2Cl + Cl* -> Ph-CHCl* + HCl}$$

Comment: After dichlorination on methyl group of toluene, why can't a third chlorine attach on the benzylic carbon?